# How to highlight UIButton over UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicolor

How to set `UIButton` highlight while click please help me for i am totally stuck in this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.leaveDetailTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? LeaveDetailCell
    cell!.cellCardView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.8941176471, blue: 0.6549019608, alpha: 1)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.leaveDetailTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? LeaveDetailCell
    cell!.cellCardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

When I select a table view item I have to highlight a particular row with color I want to choose my own color.

Comment: What is not working? Why are you using the `didHighlightRowAt` and `didUnhighlightRowAt` delegate methods if you want to do the highlighting on cell selection?

Comment: i want to highlight Uibutton while tap ....but colour is not default

Comment: You want to change the entire cell background or only the button color inside your cell?

Comment: only button colour Highlight

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to change the color when the button is clicked 
First, you should add an action to your button

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(_:)))
cell.cellCardView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

After you do this, inside the action `handleTapGesture(_:)` you can change the color of your button like this

```
func handleTapGesture(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.8941176471, blue: 0.6549019608, alpha: 1)
    }) { (_) in
        sender.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Robert Dresler's answer will work for a cell which is selected, not highlighted. My go to would be to create a subclass of UITableViewCell, in this way you abstract this code away from the rest of your logic and create something that is reusable. I'll provide a quick example;

```
class HighlightTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var highlightColor: UIColor {
        didSet {
            highlightView.backgroundColor = highlightColor
        }
    }

    private var highlightView: UIView = UIView()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        selectionStyle = .none

        addSubview(highlightView)
        highlightView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        bringSubview(toFront: highlightView)
    }

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

        highlightView.isHidden = !highlighted
        highlightView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```